# How to link information in different spreadsheets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, excel-2016

I'm on a project in which I have to link datas in order to put it in categories, sub-categories, families... I have up to 750 products, and 25 categories.

Let me explain with examples:

A first part include 2 categories

- Food
- Beverages

In those categories, I need to include sub-categories:
For food:

- Sandwich
- Salads
- ...

For Beverages:

- Hot Beverages
- Cold Beverages
- Sodas
- ...

In each of those sub-categories, I need to include all my products:

- Club sandwich
- French sandwich
- Caesar Salad
- Norwegian Salad
- ...

Could you please tell me which tool should be the easier using excel? And how to set it up?
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Create three sheets. One for Category, one for sub-category and another for product.  On the product sheet add columns for sub-category and category. Then follow the instructs in the link below to add drop-downs for sub-category and category.

[Excel create a drop-down list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-drop-down-list-7693307a-59ef-400a-b769-c5402dce407b)

[image]